# Store the newest 100 numbers. (delete old ones)

Tags: python, performance

The task is to store the newest ~100 numbers and calculate their sum.

I would like to optimize for time-performance.

Usage: In the context of sequence alignment, after creating a 2D scoring-matrix between 2 sequences, starting at the bottom right corner, I want to search for the optimal alignment path. Here I adapt previous alignment algorithms to search for the optimal alignment at a fixed alignment length. For this, the sum of the previous path isn't sufficient, but instead I want to save the values of the previous path into each cell.

```
storage = []
new_number = 1

def store_numbers(storage, new_number, storage_size = 100):
    storage.append(new_number)
    if len(storage)>storage_size:
        del storage[0]
    return storage, sum(storage)


#test
for x in range(100):
    print(store_numbers(storage, x, storage_size = 10)
```

Ideas: Avoid the function? Avoid append() - del() and instead overwrite? Instead of list use Numpy array or something else?

Comment: Can you add some details about what this function is used for(not what it does)?

Comment: post the actual context of calling `store_numbers` function (not fictitious printing)

Comment: Keep track of the sum incerementally. When adding item to the queue make addition to the sum. When a number Is being extracted from the queue subtract it from the sum. When consumer asks for sum return the accumulated value.

Comment: Is this your real code? What's the actual usage look like? You're missing a `)` on your last line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make your life way easier if you used the [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) data structure.

```
from collections import deque

d = deque(maxlen=2)
d.append(1)
d.append(2)
d.append(3)

sum(d)  # gives 5, which is the sum of the last two inserted elements.
```

With this, you call the `sum` function only when you really need to, which will improve your performance if you don't need the sum every time (like when you're first populating the container).

Also, `deque` probably has faster length checking internally than using `len` onto a list.

Comment: Thanks, that's a really handy solution! And it seems to run really fast!

Answer (score 0):

I had a bit too much fun playing with this and came up with a circular list implementation with a running total that's not much of a win (or sometimes even slower) for smaller sizes but gets a lot faster as you scale up.  The fun part was coming up with a nice framework for testing different implementations with different sizes (I used both your original implementation and Ignacio's deque as references) -- even if my implementation isn't useful for your case I hope it serves as a good example of test-driven development.  :)

```
from abc import abstractmethod
from collections import deque
from time import time
from typing import Deque, Iterable, List, Tuple, Type

class NumberStorage:

    def __init__(self, storage_size: int) -> None:
        self._capacity = storage_size

    @abstractmethod
    def store(self, new_number: int) -> Tuple[Iterable[int], int]:
        """
        Stores the new number, dropping the oldest number if capacity is exceeded.
        Returns an iterable of all the stored numbers, and their sum.
        """
        pass

class NaiveStorage(NumberStorage):

    def __init__(self, storage_size: int) -> None:
        super().__init__(storage_size)
        self._storage: List[int] = []

    def store(self, new_number: int) -> Tuple[List[int], int]:
        self._storage.append(new_number)
        if len(self._storage) > self._capacity:
            del self._storage[0]
        return self._storage, sum(self._storage)

class DequeStorage(NumberStorage):

    def __init__(self, storage_size: int) -> None:
        super().__init__(storage_size)
        self._storage: Deque[int] = deque(maxlen=storage_size)

    def store(self, new_number: int) -> Tuple[Deque[int], int]:
        self._storage.append(new_number)
        return self._storage, sum(self._storage)

class CircularStorage(NumberStorage):

    def __init__(self, storage_size: int) -> None:
        super().__init__(storage_size)
        self._oldest = 0
        self._total = 0
        self._storage: List[int] = []

    def store(self, new_number: int) -> Tuple[List[int], int]:
        self._total += new_number
        if len(self._storage) < self._capacity:
            self._storage.append(new_number)
        else:
            self._total -= self._storage[self._oldest]
            self._storage[self._oldest] = new_number
            self._oldest += 1
            if self._oldest == self._capacity:
                self._oldest = 0
        return self._storage, self._total

def test_storage(
    storage_type: Type[NumberStorage], 
    capacity: int, 
    iterations: int, 
) -> None:
    start_time = time()
    storage = storage_type(capacity)
    for x in range(iterations):
        _, total = storage.store(x)
    print("{}\t(max={}, n={}) \tsum: {}\ttime : {}".format(
        storage_type.__name__,
        capacity,
        iterations,
        total,
        time() - start_time),
    )

for capacity, iterations in [(10**1, 10**2), (10**2, 10**4), (10**3, 10**6)]:
    for storage in (NaiveStorage, DequeStorage, CircularStorage):
        test_storage(storage, capacity, iterations)
```

My output is:

```
NaiveStorage    (max=10, n=100)         sum: 945        time : 0.0
DequeStorage    (max=10, n=100)         sum: 945        time : 0.0
CircularStorage (max=10, n=100)         sum: 945        time : 0.0
NaiveStorage    (max=100, n=10000)      sum: 994950     time : 0.014982223510742188
DequeStorage    (max=100, n=10000)      sum: 994950     time : 0.0159609317779541
CircularStorage (max=100, n=10000)      sum: 994950     time : 0.009946107864379883
NaiveStorage    (max=1000, n=1000000)   sum: 999499500  time : 12.579213619232178
DequeStorage    (max=1000, n=1000000)   sum: 999499500  time : 13.003407716751099
CircularStorage (max=1000, n=1000000)   sum: 999499500  time : 1.1614789962768555
```

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].

Comment: As long as you are storing information (storage size) with the object, you could also store the "start" position.  Then no size tests or Deque function calls are needed to save a new number; simply store it at position `[start++%size]`.